# Sparkle Shows Message "Your App is Up to Date" every time on launch after updating

Tags: macos, auto-update, silent-installer, sparkle

I am using Sparkle framework for updating my Mac app . The updation is successfully done . But now after the updation on every launch of the application user gets a message "Your App is Up to Date". How can i disable this message on every launch ?

I am using **SUUpdater.shared.checkForUpdateInformation()**  and uses the delegates

**- (void)updater:(SUUpdater *)updater didFindValidUpdate:(SUAppcastItem *)update;**

**- (void)updaterDidNotFindUpdate:(SUUpdater *)update;**

when a  valid update is found i will call **SUUpdater.shared.installUpdatesIfAvailable**

Is this making the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

ok . 
Now i got the problem after playing around a bit. The delegate need to be set correctly on SUUpdater shared instance. After setting delegate it all works as expected.

Comment: You should show us how to setup delegate correctly?